# When to free allocated memory in mex file

Tags: c, matlab, memory, malloc, mex

I have some questions about mxMalloc and mxFree for allocating memory in mex code. Assume I am converting C code to Matlab and I allocate memory like this:

```
in= mxMalloc(sizeof(double)*N);

in =mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
```

However when later on I free the memory using

```
 mxFree(in)
```

I receive segmentation violation error. I wonder can `anyone explain when I should realize I should free and allocate the memory. what type of pointers should be freed and what type should not be freed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here. First of all you allocate memory and have the pointer `in` point to this fresh data.

```
in = mxMalloc(sizeof(double)*N);
```

This is completely unnecessary since you then abandon this data, and instead have the pointer `in` point to one of the *inputs that MATLAB provides to your function*.

```
in = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
```

`in` now refers to data that MATLAB has provided to your function and MATLAB expects this data to remain there. If you call `mxFree` to free it up, MATLAB then is unable to access this data when it attempts to access it later causing your segmentation violation error.

If you hadn't re-assigned `in` to point to the input data, you could  use `mxFree` to free it up only if you do not plan on passing a pointer to that data back to MATLAB.

```
in = mxMalloc(sizeof(double) * N);
mxFree(in);
```

Comment: I really appropriate your answer but what if I am not passing data back I read in other documents that memory allocated by mxMalloc will be automatically freed when program ends.can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Thank you so much. I was wondering in  is pointing to the input Matlab provides and my output from mex to Matlab is something else. So why should it be a problem to free in because I do manipulation on in and at the end of program I will free in after matlab passed the input and do all the calculation then I type mxFree(in).

Comment: @justin It is recommended to *not* modify `in` as that will modify the inputs that the user passes to your function in place. Instead, `mxMalloc` as you have and make a *copy* of the input, modify that, and return it (without calling `mxFree`).